# Java android eclipse can not use method Settings.System.canWrite(context)

Tags: java, android

I have a project in eclipse and I can not use a method

```
Settings.System.canWrite(context)
```

What I should to do , to repair this ?

Now I have the method canWrite is undefined for the type Settings.System

Comment: why can't you use it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have Now I have the method canWrite is undefined for the type Settings.System

Comment: 1) you are probably using wrong `Settings.System`. Check the package name of what you are using. 2) `canWrite` was added in API 23, so you are probably using older API

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I used this : import android.provider.Settings;
  and how in eclipse I check verssio this API ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that in eclipse. As you are working with it, you should know how to do that. I'm working with Android Studio as Eclipse is deprecated for couple years already.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko when I migrate to Andorid Studio I have this same probleme

Comment: it does not matter. As I said, the sdk version you are using does matter.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have Project Build target Android 6.0 (API 23)